# Strange behavior with gcc on MCU, code skips lines if no breakpoint is inserted

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, soc

I have a project using FreeRTOS on a SoC by Microsemi called SmartFusion2.

Here's the part that's not executed.

```
struct buffer{
    uint8_t version;
    //other members
};

i2c_read(&i2c_handler, DATA_ID, (uint8_t*)&buffer, DATA_LEN);

if(buffer.version != 0x05){

    DEBUG_PRINT("Copying done. Running the program\n");
    //some i2c transfer here
    vTaskDelay(500);
    status = i2c_read(&i2c_handler, DATA_ID, (uint8_t*)&buffer, DATA_LEN);

    if(status > 0){
            vTaskDelay(10000);
            //some more i2c operation here
            if(buffer.version != 0x05){
                DEBUG_PRINT("Started in bootloader mode\n");
            } else {
                DEBUG_PRINT("Success\n");
            }
    } else {
       DEBUG_PRINT("Failed connecting\n");
    }
} else {
    DEBUG_PRINT("OK\n");
}
```

The output is only this.

> Copying done. Running the program

I am definitely sure it is not just a printing/UART problem because it skips over the 10 second delay as well and continues executing the next tasks.

However, when I insert a breakpoint on the line that prints it and step over, one of the next DEBUG_PRINT statements is executed normally (in this case, "Started in bootloader mode").

Could this have something to do with optimization? I use -Os. I don't think adding a breakpoint would change anything in that case though. Any ideas what could be the case here?

Comment: After the code is compiled and optimized, there is no more 1-to-1 correspondence with the source code lines. So in debugger you might see that the execution is skipping some code sections, or executing them not in order.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm not talking about skipped lines in debugger, I'm talking about the output

Comment: Then your program is simply stuck in one of these functions, which probably depend on timing (i'd suspect `i2c_read`). When stepping over, you are changing the timing, so it succeeds. You need to isolate that function and take a closer look to what is going on. Or you have some other bugs which are impossible to spot without seeing the full code

Comment: your code is basically not very RTOS. 10s delays will not help at all. Move i2c to its task and when data is ready send it to the handling task.

Comment: I know it's not stuck because the main function that calls the function that has the lines I posted here keeps executing afterwards.


About not being very RTOS, I'd agree, but I never had a problem with i2c before.

Comment: @EserRose Again, there are many possible reasons for such a behavior. For example that your "DEBUG_PRINT" requires some delay between executions. For example, if the UART has a limited buffer size which does not have time to empty, so the next messages are dropped. Again, you need to isolate what exactly is happening - is it only the output which is missing, or some other functionality too.